# UIbutton 's image not changing

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I made a breadcrumb navigation which shows the title of each cell which you select. For the first screen - before a cell is selected I want to show a **home icon**. After one cell gets selected I want to change the icon.

```
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 44, height: 44))
        breadcrumbsTitles.count <= 1 ? button.setImage(UIImage(named: "home_1x"), for: .normal) : button.setImage(UIImage(named: "arrow_left"), for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(backPressed), for: .touchUpInside)

//container for the bread crumb navigation 
container.addSubview(button)
```

---

***breadcrumbsTitles*** contains all the cells/views in my container:

```
public var breadcrumbsTitles: [String] {
        return self.viewControllers.map {
            $0.title ?? ""
        }
    }
```

---

```
breadcrumbsTitles.count
```

returns the number of titles in the bread crumb navigation. 
Why is my button not changing its image when one cell is selected? I also tried to use a **if-else** statement but it does not work either:

```
if breadcrumbsTitles.count <= 1{
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "home_1x"), for: .normal)
} else ... // set image to "arrow_left"
```

Why is my image of my button not changing after I select a cell or something else?

Comment: try `button.setImage(UIImage(named:"home_1x")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)`

Comment: Didn´t work. Tried it in the if else statement and the other way.

Comment: Try and use the ui debug tool to see if the button is visible, and its not getting blocked by another view

Comment: The **else** statement is never reached somehow. I debugged it and saw that it never jumps into it.

Comment: @freyli-C - you need to show some more code... for example, you haven't shown what you are doing with `breadcrumbsTitles`. Might be a good idea to review [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

> Your container is not ready to add more addSubview view first you can
>   correct container view then working fine.

1. i am add in viewDidLoad is working fine and properly

import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let breadcrumbsTitles = ["1","2","3"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 44, height: 44))
        breadcrumbsTitles.count <= 1 ? button.setImage(UIImage(named: "default"), for: .normal) : button.setImage(UIImage(named: "arrow_left"), for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnPress), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        self.view.addSubview(button)

    }


    @objc func btnPress() {


    }


}
```